# Solaris 11.2 extended permissions shown by ls

Tags: files, permissions, solaris, ls, acl

I have a file that shows up as having extended file permissions.

```
ls -V /usr/share/X11/app-defaults/XScreenSaver
rwx------   1 root     root          53 Dec  2 21:52 /usr/share/X11/appdefaults/XScreenSaver
          owner@:rwxp--aARWcCos:-------:allow
          group@:------a-R-c--s:-------:allow
          everyone@:------a-R-c--s:-------:allow
```

How do I remove extended attributes?

Solaris 11.2

Comment: You seem to have confused _Access Control Lists (ACLs)_ with _Extended Attributes_. `ls -V` shows the Access Control Lists on Solaris.  Extended attributes is a different feature that allows setting attributes such as `appendonly` or `immutable` that are shown via `ls -/` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This file has no extended attributes (actually ACLs), or more precisely, what you see in the `owner@`, `group@` and `everyone@` lines are the default ACLs for a `0700` file.

Should you really want to remove for all users outside the owner even the ability to know the attributes of the file itself, you might at your own risks use these (untested on that file) commands:

```
# chmod A-group@:aRcs:allow /usr/share/X11/appdefaults/XScreenSaver
# chmod A-everyone@:aRcs:allow /usr/share/X11/appdefaults/XScreenSaver
# chmod A+everyone@::allow /usr/share/X11/appdefaults/XScreenSaver
# chmod A+group@::allow /usr/share/X11/appdefaults/XScreenSaver
```

Answer (score 1):

Files and directories which have ACLs are identified with a + sign at the right side of the permission mask ie.: `-rw-r--r--+`

To remove ACLs you should use `chmod A- /usr/share/X11/app-defaults/XScreenSaver`

See also `man ls` and search for explanation of the `-l` argument and `man chmod` and search for `A-`